# Get Document OuterHTML of MVC Application in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

We need to export the entire page of MVC Application to PDF for that purpose  need to get all the HTML contents (i.e. including dynamic content too)

To get the contents of page we used following code

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

but **it will give only static content of page**(i.e. it gives page source code) not new nodes added in DOM.

Then tried following code **but this also gives static content**

```
// WebClient object
WebClient client = new WebClient();

// Retrieve resource as a stream
Stream data = client.OpenRead(new Uri("xxxx.html"));

// Retrieve the text
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string htmlContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

So i want to get enitre outerHTML of document in C# **with out using any third party DLL** . i googled so many links and everyone updated like use **webbrowser control** and get the content.

i don't how this will be useful for our application. Our Application is MVC4. we need to export the enitre page  to PDF so we need enitre content OF HTML (dynamic content too)

How can i use this below code in ourt MVC Application  to get document outerHTML

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
string html = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

or

```
var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)webBrowser.Document.DomDocument;

StringReader sr = new StringReader(documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.outerHTML); 

htmlDoc.Load(sr)
```

Any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what the PDF is intended for. Most likely it is for the visitor of the page to download. If that is true, maybe you could use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). That way you get around the problem with not having access to the entire page serverside.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want to do in server side.i knew so many plugins avail to do in client side but expecting to do in C# only

Comment: Ah OK. But still, maybe the way to go is with javascript. Get all the content from the client, and send it to some action method on the server.